# How do BluRay players or washing machine run Java programs?

Tags: java

What OS do they use for example and how to they boot up so quickly (compared to a raspberry pi)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. Also you should ask the manufacturer of the device, there's a few different options (e.g.: they could be running Android, some custom OS, Java Embedded, ...)

Comment: Without knowing what particular device you're talking about, we couldn't know.

Comment: Well sorry, what would be the correct community where I can ask this?

Comment: General computing can be addressed in [su]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, they are two option existing:

- they are running a custom piece of software that support a jvm
- they are running a minimum version of a linux , just what's enough to run the jvm, everything else is disabled / removed.

It's booting that fast because it has only the piece of code needed to run a minimal jvm, and everything else is disabled in opposition of the raspberry pi who has a complete kernel, with a lot of modules, a desktop environment, etc, ... to load.